# Is down-voting based on tone appropriate?

Tags: discussion, answers, voting, etiquette

I've noticed a few users writing answers with fairly patronizing and dismissive tones such as: "your fear ... is silly. You'd have to do something pretty stupid..." or suggesting that the premise of a question is "nonsense" or "totally absurd."

Would it be better to a) edit these questions to soften the tone, or b) downvote the answer (which might otherwise contain good information).

Comment: I dislike downvoting, unless you also make a comment to say why it was downvoted.  Lots of people do not understand how they come across in print, and write things, that if said in the right tone, would indicate that they are mildly mocking, or making a joke.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you can find a way to make the answer sound nicer without changing the meaning, I'd prefer that solution. Otherwise, consider whether it actually answers the question and, if not, flag it as "not an answer."

Comment: I agree with Kevin.

Comment: Nietsche said "Convictions are more dangerous enemies of truth than lies". A harsh tone can deprive an answer of its genuine content.

Comment: Nietsche and I have spent many a long morning in the Great Outdoors... nice one @Amine